# Run different dockers with R

Tags: r, docker

I want to run in separeted dockers R processes, so if a docker fails, the others continues runing.

I dont know if I have to use docker-compose to do this, or maybe create differnt docker files and run all of them

Which is the better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to do this would be with kubernetes or docker swarm, both built on top of docker